# Do Qt queued signals provide memory fences?

Tags: c++, qt

If I change something in memory that isn't related to the signal parameters before emitting (`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`), will the other thread see these modifications?

Comment: Since memory is typically on-process basis (not thread basis) by the OS, you could arange to access to that memory, though this is probably not what you asked for. Maybe you should add what exactly the problem is or what your intentions are.

Comment: @SebastianLange, I'll rephrase. If you're writing the same memory from one thread and reading from another - it's a race condition. If you write to the memory from one thread, then block on BlockingQueuedConnection, then read the same memory from the second thread (the thread that receives the emitted signal) - is it a race condition too?

Comment: Much better. From my understanding, yes this should work. Funny thing is you are using the signal as some kind of mutex. If you can afford your thread to be blocking for that long, not only the read/write part but also the queueing and waiting in the event queue (16ms?), then this should actually work. Still I would prefer to have a `QMutex` which can be locked on access of your memory object.

Comment: @SebastianLange, the intention was to wait until the slot completes execution, and to do it with the simplest code. The doubt is the following: data is not related to the signal/slot parameters, so the signal/slot mechanism is probably not required to guarantee that it's safe to read it.

Comment: Since the complete thread is blocking the data shouldn't be modified at all during the wait.

Comment: @SebastianLange, that's not how it works. If the data is not modified, but the caches of different cores/processors aren't synced - then the second thread won't read the data that the first thread has written before going to sleep.

Comment: this could be true for unsynced access. Typical multicores nowadays should not have this problem or we never yet encountered it. We even did not encounter it on multiprocessor boards with multicore-processors so far. Nevertheless, since we use a BlockingQueuedConnection (Queued) this is not a instant call on the other thread but added to the event queue. This should give enough time to write back to RAM.